# PDF - Character shows up as blank on PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I installed two `Noto Sans` fonts, the first is `Noto Sans JP Regular` and the other is `Noto Sans CJK JP Regular`. I got both fonts from https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/

I tried testing PDF publish (using iText library) with the japanese character 人. This character should be in both fonts (tested using text editor).

However, when I publish the pdf, the character is only visible using the `Noto Sans CJK JP Regular` font.

When I use the `Noto Sans JP Regular`, the character seems to exist, but is a blank character. If i highlight the blank character and view text properties using PDF-xChange viewer, then I can see that the character does exist and should be embedded on the page (see screenshot). How can i fix this so that the character is visible in the PDF?

[image]

For comparison, this is what it looks like with the `Noto Sans CJK JP regular` font

[image]

Comment: What's "Noto Sans JP Regular" (without the CJK part) though? The only official Japanese font in the sans-serif Noto family is "Noto Sans CJK JP".

Comment: It's the font file under 'Region-specific Subset OpenType/CFF (Subset OTF)' from https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/. According to the flowchart, it seems like the recommendation for linux systems.